# Setting language option in Leaflet.Routing.Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

UPDATED:

I am trying to translate the leaflet routing component with language:'sp'
 but it does not work for me.

```
const createRoutingControl = () => {
L.Routing.control({      
  router: L.Routing.mapbox(config.features.routing.key),      
  plan: new (L.Routing.Plan.extend({
    createGeocoders: function () {
      let container = L.Routing.Plan.prototype.createGeocoders.call(this)
      let reverseRoute = createButton('&#8593;&#8595;', container)
      let copyToClipboard = createButton('5', container, true)       

      return container
    }
  }))([], {
    geocoder: geocoder,
    language: 'sp'
  }),
  units: config.features.routing.units,
  showAlternatives: true,
  autoRoute: true,
  routeWhileDragging: true,      
}).addTo(map)
```

}

With " language:'sp' " **the form is traslated but not the instruccions**.
I know I have to use formatter but I tried to put it in routing.control, routing.plan... (and more places only to test it) and it does not work (the map is not displayed)

Comment: Add the language option as parameter of the mapbox function, when creating the "router" : ... router: L.Routing.mapbox(config.features.routing.key, {language: 'sp'}),

Answer (score 2):

The response from @IvanSanchez is almost correct: `Control` does indeed not have a `language` option, but several other classes have (not sure this is even properly documented, sorry).

Having said that, as a default, the `Control` class passes on any option you give it when it instantiates its child components, so passing `language` as an option to `Control` will also pass it to the default formatter, the router, etc. The exception is when you provide child components that you instantiate yourself, like the `Plan` in your example: for that case, you need to explicitly provide the options (like you already do).

So I would assume this code should fix the issue:

```
const createRoutingControl = () => {
L.Routing.control({      
  router: L.Routing.mapbox(config.features.routing.key),      
  plan: new (L.Routing.Plan.extend({
    createGeocoders: function () {
      let container = L.Routing.Plan.prototype.createGeocoders.call(this)
      let reverseRoute = createButton('&#8593;&#8595;', container)
      let copyToClipboard = createButton('5', container, true)       

      return container
    }
  }))([], {
    geocoder: geocoder,
    language: 'sp'
  }),
  units: config.features.routing.units,
  showAlternatives: true,
  autoRoute: true,
  routeWhileDragging: true,
  language: 'sp'
}).addTo(map)
```

Comment: Thanks Liedman. I added " language: 'sp' " ( inside routing.control ) like you but nothing. Instruccions are in English

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to dig up this topic, but I can not translate the instructions in french...

I set the language  option 'fr' directly in L.Routing.control and also in the formatter...

I try to debug the lines where the localization is done, and I see my problem at line 16353 of leaflet-routing-machine.js :

```
    formatInstruction: function(instr, i) {
        if (instr.text === undefined) {
            return this.capitalize(L.Util.template(this._getInstructionTemplate(instr, i),
                .....
                })));
        } else {
            return instr.text;
        }
```

where instr.text is already initialized...

If I reset instr.text to "undefined" at debug time, the instruction is well translated...

Do you have any idea of my problem?
My code is below:

```js
$script(['https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js'], () =>{
$script(['https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js'], () => {

this.map = L.map(element);

L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="//osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>  - rendu <a href="//openstreetmap.fr">OSM France</a> ',
maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(this.map);      


this.map = L.map(element);

L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="//osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>  - rendu <a href="//openstreetmap.fr">OSM France</a> ',
 maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(this.map);      

let control1 = L.Routing.control(
 {
  router: L.routing.mapbox(this.key.MapboxKey),   
    
  language: 'fr',
  formatter:  new L.Routing.Formatter({
   language: 'fr' 
  }),

  waypoints: [
   L.latLng(47.928927, 7.538860),
   L.latLng(48.044444, 7.299279),
   L.latLng(47.857503, 6.821690),
   L.latLng(47.506390, 6.996181),
   L.latLng(47.586881, 7.25652)
  ],
  routeWhileDragging: true
 })
 .on('routingerror', function(e) {
  try {
   this.map.getCenter();
  } catch (e) {
   this.map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(control1.getWaypoints().map(function(wp) { return wp.latLng; })));
  }

  handleError(e);
 })
 .addTo(this.map);
L.Routing.errorControl(control1).addTo(this.map);
```

====================================================================

As I found the **solution** in the meantime, I give it away because it seems not to be documented :

I have to add the language option as parameter of the mapbox function, when creating the "router" :

```
L.routing.mapbox(this.key.MapboxKey, {language: 'fr'}),
```

Comment: it worked for me when adding 'pt-BR', thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of RTFM.

If you look a bit closer at the [API documentation for Leaflet Routing Machine](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/), you'll notice that `L.Routing.Control` does **not** have a `language` option, and that the `language` option only applies to instances of `L.Routing.Formatter`, and that a `L.Routing.Control` can take a `formatter` option which can hold an instance of `L.Routing.Formatter`. So putting everything together...

```
L.Routing.control({
  router: L.Routing.mapbox(config.features.routing.key),     
  formatter: L.Routing.formatter({
    language: 'sp'
    units: config.features.routing.units,
  }),
  showAlternatives: true,
  autoRoute: true,
  // ... etc
},
```

---

(P.S.: "prop" is reactjs slang, and that word does not apply here)